# apache - redirect to domain root while maintaining URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm using apache web server with PHP.

I'm trying to redirect all entries to a directory to the root folder

meaning - if a user goes to `mydomain.com/vendors/me` I want him to be redirected to the index under documentroot and I want to be able to to get the `vendors/me` part of the url through $_SERVER and do some business logic according to it.

I know rewriteEngine engine is the way to go i just couldn't find a way of achieving that.

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^vendors/me/?$ / [L,NC]
```

to load home page for above URI and and access `/vendors/me/` using `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` variable.

Answer (score 0):

the solution i went with was this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^vend/(.*) / [PT]
```

which redirects to root directory and while preserving the full URL...